# apacheが二重になっていないか確認する方法

Tags: php, apache, mamp

macOS high Sierra ヴァージョン10.13.6です。

mampをインストールしましたが、
標準搭載しているapache又は以前にインストールしたかもしれないapacheと
mampのapacheが二重になっているのか、ブラウザではIt works!と表示されるのに、
mampではApache Serverが起動していません。

mampの状態ですが、

```
[start/stop]
when starting camp:check for updatesとopen web start pageにチェック
when quitting camp:stop serversにチェック
[ports]
apache port:80
nginx port:80
mysql port:3306
[php]
standard version:7.2.1
[web server]
web server:apache
document root:
>Desktop>fuel>public
[mysql]
active version:5.6.38
[cloud]
チェックしている項目なし
```

apacheが二重になっていないかどうかを探るベストな方法をご教示下さいませんか。
お手数おかけしますが何卒よろしくお願いします。

Comment: `apache`と`nginx`のportが共に`80`となっています。もしかしたら`It works!`は`nginx`が出力していて、`apache`は`80`ポートを`nginx`に奪われているため起動できないのかもしれません。`apache`か`nginx`のいずれかのポートを`8080`などのかぶらないポートに変えると上手くいくかもしれません。

Comment: ありがとうございます。試して見ます。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ターミナルを開き、以下のコマンドを実行すると、80番ポートを開いているプロセスがわかります。

```
lsof -i:80
```

ブラウザで`http://localhost`にアクセスして、`It works!`と表示されるのであれば、上記コマンドで表示されるプロセスが`It works!`を出力していると思います。

Comment: lsof -i:80を実行すると何もプロセスが表示されないのに、It works!が表示されます。

Comment: `It works!`はブラウザにどういうURLを設定したときに表示されますか?(http://localhost/ですか?)

Comment: It woks!はURLをlocalhostに設定したら表示されます。

Comment: `lsof -i -P | grep "LISTEN"`を実行した場合になにが表示されるでしょうか?

Comment: ```lsof -i -P | grep "LISTEN"```を実行しても何も表示されません

Comment: `lsof -i -P | grep "LISTEN"`で何も表示されないのであれば、apache, nginxもmysqlも起動していないように思います。

Comment: mampを開くと、cloudとmysql serverは起動していますよ。Apache serverだけ```Apache couldn't be started. Please check your MAMP installation and configuration. ```と表示されている状態です。

Comment: サーバの起動しているしてないのチェックの際にはブラウザ側でのキャッシュクリアが絶対必須です。毎回キャッシュクリアして、ないしは必ずスーパーリロードする形で試してください。

Comment: キャッシュクリアするとlocalhostとURLに打ち込んでもIt works!が表示されなくなりました

Comment: ということはやはり http サーバは起動していないということです。

Comment: ごめんさい。今度は`sudo lsof -i -P | grep "LISTEN"`を実行してもらえませんか?(sudoを実行しているためご自身のログインパスワードを入力する必要があります。)  lsof はプログラムが開いているポート番号を調査する良いツールです。lsofで"LISTEN"中のポート番号を調査できるようになれば、80番ポートを誰が使っているのか(orいないのか)を簡単に切り分けることができます。

Comment: @tanalab2 sudo lsof -i -P | grep "LISTEN"を実行しましたが何も表示されませんでした

Comment: お手数をおかけしました。127.0.0.1にポートスキャンしてLISTENポートは表示されるのに, lsofでは表示されないことがあるんですね。すみませんでした。一旦、私のコメントは忘れてください。